# Droplist value doesn't change

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, html-select

i want that my application change value of droplist on a site. 
This is the code of droplist on a site:

```
<select name="filterPPage">
    <option value="20"></option>
    <option value="30"></option><option value="40"></option>
    <option value="50"></option><option value="60"></option>
    <option value="70"></option><option value="80"></option>
    <option value="90"></option><option value="100"></option>
</select>
```

I use this code in my application to change value:

```
int buff = 100;

foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
{
    if (he.GetAttribute("name").Equals("filterPPage"))
    {
        he.SetAttribute("value", buff.ToString());
    }
}
```

But it change value to 100 only for a second and then page refreshes, and value become 20 as default.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must loop through `select tag` child:

Try this:

```
        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (HtmlElement selecttag in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
            {
                if (selecttag.GetAttribute("name").Equals("filterPPage"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlElement child in selecttag.All)
                    {
                        child .InnerText = "something";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

**Edited**

Complete code:

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\\file.html");
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
            {
                if (he.GetAttribute("name").Equals("filterPPage"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlElement el in he.All)
                    {
                        el.InnerText = "1==";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The same, value become 100 for a second, then page refreshes and become 20 as default

Comment: @vasa911: i don't know structure of your page but,there must be a problem with your page.see my edit it work fine for me

Comment: first code works fine. It was my mistake in previous code, thanks

Comment: @vasa911:have fun +1 from me :D